# Python - Storing integers all less than 256 with ASCII

Tags: python, compression, ascii

I have an ordered finite sequence of integers. Each integer is less than 256 and at least zero. They can be greater than 127. I want to write them to a text file using an ASCII representation so I can just have them all on one line and save memory space. (If I write them as integers, I have to have some kind of separator between each element, such as a `\t` or `\n`).

My idea was to just take each number, convert them to respective ASCII, and then when I need them later I can just go character by character and translate the ASCII character into a number.

However, I notice that characters like `Æ` are encoded in Python as actually two characters `\xc3\x86` while other characters are just one character like `@` and `D`. So my method of just going character by character to process it is not going to work out.

How can I do this using ASCII or some other method to save space?

Comment: What is the code you are having issue with?

Comment: ASCII only goes to 127, so you're going to run into issues going higher than that. If you want to save in a binary format, you could try `pickle` or something, or just use a regular text file and compress it. How big is this data file anyway?

Comment: Why not use a string? ... ```str(number_between_zero_and_256)```

Comment: Have you heard about file's binary open mode?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 each data file will have around 200 million numbers (one number for each position in one whole chromosome). I thought extended ASCII goes to 255?

Comment: @wwii, if he just writes the numbers as strings, when he reads the data back out, he won't know whether "123" is "one followed by twenty three" or "twelve followed by three" or any other combination.

Comment: @Kevin - I thought the OP stated that the numbers were going to be seperated by *whitespace*.

Comment: I interpreted "If I write them as integers, I have to have some kind of separator between each element" to mean "I don't want to write them as integers _because_ it would require whitespace, which is a waste of memory"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be pretty straightforward, just make sure to open the file `'wb'`. For example:

```
# simulate binary 
b = [chr(c) for c in xrange(256)]

# write to file
with open('file.txt', 'wb') as fout:
    fout.write(''.join(b))
```

Comment: Your first list comprehension fixes my problem. I wonder why the characters I was trying to use were two characters long, when in this case they are only one? Also, what does using the control `'wb'` do? I'm unfamiliar with it.

Comment: From docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open,  `Append 'b' to the mode to open the file in binary mode, on systems that differentiate between binary and text files; on systems that don’t have this distinction, adding the 'b' has no effect.`

Comment: I'm using a Windows machine, and it says that just `'w'` does the trick for ASCII text files. Does one use `'wb'` just to be safe?

Comment: I always use `'wb'` when dealing with binary data. It's harmless on platforms without the distinction, and you never know when multiplatform support will matter to you later.

Comment: Okay, thanks! FWI, I don't think your writing to file thing is what I want, but your list comprehension seems to fix my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use data as unsigned characters? With numpy or struct.pack, etc.